# Allowing a user to draw their own avatar in turtle

Tags: python, performance, turtle-graphics

I am working on a turtle project where the user can draw their own avatar.

The thing is, I want the user to be able to decide whether the turtle they drew will be filled, or not.

The filled part is simple, as by default, the polies will get filled,
but the only way I know how to avoid filling is to retrace the lines so that the end of the line meets the start of the line.

Is there a built-in method or a more efficient way to keep the polies empty?
The problem with my current method is that the more lines (parameter) is used for turtle, the more rocky the program runs (the area doesn't influence the smoothness of the program).

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()

pen = turtle.Turtle('circle')
pen.shapesize(0.1, 0.1)

cor = []

# function to draw with the pen
def drag(x, y):
    wn.tracer(0)
    pen.goto(x, y)
    cor.append(pen.pos())

# function to break out of while loop
def fill():
    global done
    done = True

# function to break out of while loop and set fill to False
def nofill():
    global done, fill
    done = True
    fill = False
    
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(fill, 'f')
wn.onkeypress(nofill, 'n')

pen.ondrag(drag)

done = False
fill = True

while not done:
    wn.update()
    
pen.begin_poly()

if fill:
    for c in cor:
        pen.goto(c)
else:
    for c in cor[::-1]: # first go backards, then forward to avoid fill
        pen.goto(c)
    for c in cor:
        pen.goto(c)
        
pen.end_poly()

wn.register_shape("mypen", pen.get_poly())
wn.clear()

example = turtle.Turtle('mypen')
```

Example with fill:

- Run the above code.
- Draw a shape.
- Press f

[image]

Example without fill:

- Run the above code.
- Draw a shape.
- Press n

[image]

Comment: What does this do? Could you explain how to use this, how do you change from fill to no fill? Can you show an example of both filled and nofill?

Comment: @Peilonrayz Added.

Comment: For some reason whenever I press f or n it just kicks me out of the program. I can't see the filled / no filled diamond. Looking at the code this seems about right, have you missed a little bit of code off the bottom?

Comment: @Peilonrayz It works for me, but you might need to add `wn.mainloop()` to the bottom. And just in case, you need to draw the diamond first.

Comment: Hmm, I've done that now and whilst the window stays around, the lines and pen(?) disappear. Hmm, I don't think I can help with this since I can't get it to work :(

Comment: @Peilonrayz Did you include `example = turtle.Turtle('mypen')`?

Comment: Ooops! Yeah that's got it working. It flips the image I draw but yeah that works.